# EventHandler not handling my events

Tags: eventhandler

I seem to be able to use EventHandler to handle mouse events, but not keyboard events. Here is a working example with MouseClicked -- it makes the picture smaller every time the right mouse button is clicked. For the example, the t variable is a dummy and doesn't do anything.

```
s = 1; Manipulate[EventHandler[{s, ImageResize[img, Scaled[s]]}, 
                  {{"MouseClicked", 2} :> (s = 0.9 s)}], {t, 1/2, 2}]
```

But if I replace the MouseClicked with a

```
s = 1; Manipulate[EventHandler[{s, ImageResize[img, Scaled[s]]}, 
                 {{"KeyDown", "."} :> (s = 0.9 s)}], {t, 1/2, 2}]
```

Then it doesn't change the size. It appears that the focus of the keyboard/typing is not passed to the correct level. This is basically the same as [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55689/eventhandler-not-detecting-keydown) which was asked several years ago and doesn't appear to have been successfully answered (at least none of the proposed answers works in my case).

Comment: This work for `"x"`, not `"."`, if you click the image before pressing the key (hardly a sarisfactory solution): `CellPrint[
 ExpressionCell[
  Manipulate[
   EventHandler[{s, 
     ImageResize[img, 
      Scaled[s]]}, {{"KeyDown", "x"} :> (s = 0.9 s)}], {t, 1/2, 2}], 
  "Output", CellEventActions -> {PassEventsDown -> True}]]`.  Maybe it will help....

Comment: Your image double click example doesn't work with my mac trackpad...

Answer (score 3):

It is a mater of keyboard focus.

You have to use `Dynamic` wrappers within your event handler and you must have the visible value of `s` selected so it has the keyboard focus when you press <kbd>.</kbd> .

This works:

```
s = 1;
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}];
Manipulate[
  EventHandler[
    Dynamic @ {s, ImageResize[img, Scaled[s]]},
    {{"KeyDown", "."} :> (s = 0.9 s)}],
 {t, 1/2, 2}]
```

but you have to reselect the value of `s` each time after pressing <kbd>.</kbd> because the focus is lost. This works better because the value of `s` keeps the focus.

```
s = 1; 
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}];
Manipulate[
  EventHandler[
    {Dynamic @ s, Dynamic @ ImageResize[img, Scaled[s]]},
    {{"KeyDown", "."} :> (s = 0.9 s)}],
 {t, 1/2, 2}]
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks -- this is a great improvement, though still not perfect. The reason I wish to use the keyboard commands is because I have already overloaded the mouse with things it needs to click and right-click on... so it's not practical to have to click somewhere to keep the focus in the right place. But thanks for trying!

Comment: @bills. I think in your place I would consider implementing the additional actions with buttons rather than keystrokes.

Comment: Yes, I think that's a good idea... I may try a palette (CreatePalette) with some buttons or checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the output in its own notebook, you could use `NotebookEventActions`:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
  NotebookEventActions -> {{"KeyDown", "."} :> (s = 0.9 s)}];

s = 1;
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Aerial"}];
Manipulate[
 {s, ImageResize[img, Scaled[s]]},
 {t, 1/2, 2}]
```

[image]

I would pick a different character than `"."` perhaps.  The user cannot enter in a period or `Dot`.  For instance the following works for <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+`.` on a Mac:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
  NotebookEventActions -> {
    {"KeyDown", "."} :> If[CurrentValue["ControlKey"], (s = 0.9 s)], 
    PassEventsDown :> ! CurrentValue["ControlKey"]}];
```

Typing a regular `.` and a <kbd>Control</kbd>+`.` are processed as normal, and <kbd>Option</kbd>+`.` becomes `\[GreaterEqual]` also like normal.  This has to do, I assume, with precedence of menu actions over notebook events and how keyboard typing is translated into key-down events.

---

*Update*

One could also use `CellEventActions`.  For this to work, you have to click in the output cell.

```
CellPrint[
 ExpressionCell[
  Manipulate[{s, ImageResize[img, Scaled[s]]}, {t, 1/2, 2}],
  "Output",
  CellEventActions -> {
    {"KeyDown", "."} :> (s = 0.9 s)}
  ]
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to m_goldberg and Michael E2 for their insights. Unfortunately, the use of keyboard shortcuts seems finicky. What I ended up doing was to use the Mouse click along with control/option/shift keys (using the CurrentValue hint from Michael E2's post).

What this (toy version) does is to use the mouse and to grow the picture for control-click and to shrink the picture for shift-control-click. The advantage is that there is no need to worry about the focus: as long as the mouse is inside the Manipulate, it functions as desired.

```
s = 1; img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Aerial"}];
Manipulate[EventHandler[{s, ImageResize[img, Scaled[s]]}, 
 "MouseClicked" :> 
    Which[CurrentValue["ControlKey"] && CurrentValue["ShiftKey"], (s = 0.9 s), 
    CurrentValue["ControlKey"] && Not[CurrentValue["ShiftKey"]], (s = 1.1 s)]], 
{t, 1/2, 2}]
```